# Blazor causing all children to re-render (firstRender is true) instead of a differential update

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor element which has a CascadingValue.

```html
<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm EditContext="@EditContext" Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmitInternal" >
    <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
        <CascadingValue Value="@CurrentFormState" Name="FormState" >
        @ChildContent(EditContext!)
        </CascadingValue>
    </Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>
```

Here is the relevant bits in my `@code` block.

```cs
 private FormStateContext CurrentFormState { get; set; } = new();


    private void SetState(FormState s)

        CurrentFormState.State = s;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private async Task OnValidSubmitInternal(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext context)
    {

        SetState(FormState.Submitting);
        try
        {
            await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync();
            SetState(FormState.Success);
        }
        catch (HttpProblemException e)
        {
            // [...] omitted code.
            SetState(FormState.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // [...] omitted code.
            SetState(FormState.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            SetState(FormState.Idle);
        }
    }
```

The call to `StateHasChanged()` seems to render the whole sub-tree of `ChildContent` from scratch. That is, in `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)`, `firstRender` is `true`. Without calling `StateHasChanged()` the cascading value is never updated on descendant components which use it.

Why is my whole subtree being re-rendered when `StateHasChanged()` is called? No only is this poor performance, but it breaks other javascript interop libraries which mount to an actual element on the page. In my case, stripe.js isn't working because blazor is deleting and recreating the DOM elements instead of just updating via the normal diff.

I've tried adding an `@key` attribute on the EditForm, but the `ChildContent` still renders from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm` when both `EditContext` and `Model` are passed into the element. I fixed this by doing something like the following:

```html
@if (Model != null)
    {
                            <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm Model="@Model" >
      // ....
                        </Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>
    }
    else
    {
                          <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm EditContext="@EditContext"  >
// ...
                                </Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>
    }
```

With this, my whole sub tree doesn't render from scratch again.